# Parody of "Der Inder" telecom advertisment by ...?

Tags: austrian

Some years ago I saw a comedian on Austrian TV. His show featured a parody of the "Der Inder" advertisments of an Austrian telecom company. It went like "Mamma, sie hamma an andan Tarif andraht" and so on. So he was using the "a-vocalism" of Viennese dialect to depict the Indian accent. This was especially amusing for me, as I am into early linguistic history, where it is often claimed that certain languages had an a-vocalism. Unfortunately I can't recall the name of the artist, it was a mid/older age man. Does somebody know the name of the comedian (not the actor in the spots)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it aks for the name of a person which has nothing to do with German language.

Answer (score 2):

That campaign ran in 2008 and was advertising for [tele.ring](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tele.ring), a then brand of Telekom Austria.

The [campaign](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frag_doch_den_Inder) was developed by the Blink agency, the "Indian Guy" in the spots was played by the German-born Indian actor [Ramesh Nair](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramesh_Nair)

Here is a link to some spots on youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_tQbg9_b6k

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkHbymzHM54

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpvfP2D5Mqc

(I can't - at all - make out an Austrian accent in the spots I found, though. The actor seems to speak Hochdeutsch with a quite overdone Indian accent (that he doesn't have at all in reality). Also, your memory seems to trick you: The actor was 33 when he did the "Inder")

The spot even had an entry into the Austrian Pop charts, [here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbAEvPp5dPQ) a bit of background story.

Comment: I did not mean the actor in the spots, I mean the comedian who parodied it (I will edit the question to make that clear).